# how to isolate python 2.7 and 3.4 and prevent them from reading the windows registry PythonPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

All python versions including the last one 3.12 will read PythonPath from the windows registry when they are created using [this method](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/python-on-windows-setting-pythonpath-environment-variable/) ; including inside venv or virtualenv.

as the doc says :

> When running python.exe, or any other .exe in the main Python
> directory (either an installed version, or directly from the PCbuild
> directory), the core path is deduced, and the core paths in the
> registry are ignored. **Other “application paths” in the registry are
> always read.** [source](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)

so if some one adds this to the windows registry:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath\ccc]
@="D:\\tttttt27;gggggggg27;"
```

then python will happily add them to `sys.path`.

**how can I prevent this for python 2.7/3.4? (I know they are old but sometimes you are forced to use them)**

## Safe solutions:

this are the solutions I tested but non work for 2.7/3.4: `venv/virtualenv`, `-E`, `-I`, `python*._pth`, `set "PYTHONHOME=%pythonExe_dir%"`
[image]

## risked solutions:

I found a hackish solution that works but it seems a risk:

- for python `2.7`, open `python27.dll` in notepad++ for example, search for `PythonCore` word , it will be in line 22539, then change `P` to `y` and `y` to `P`, so `PythonCore` become `yPthonCore`
- for python `3.4`, open `python34.dll`, search for `PythonCore` word using this notpad++ regex: `\\\0P\0y\0t\0h\0o\0n\0C\0o\0r\0e` , it will be in line 17356, change `P` to `y` and `y` to `P`

**if there is no safe solution what implications can I suffer from using the risked solution? can something break if I edit the dll like I did?**

Comment: Why is it bad if Python 2.7 or 3.4 read from the registry?

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I send my python app to someone then I cannot be sure that it will run fine, because python will add those paths from the client registry and may create problems for my app because python will load the registry paths before using `Site`, so `lib\site-packages` will be read after the registry paths :(